# Clone library with different type

Tags: cmake

In my project we create every library as a module-library and install these.
Therefore we cannot link against these library-target in our unit-test.

```
add_library(foo MODULE foo.h foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar::bar)
install(TARGET foo DESTINATION bin)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(foo_tester fooTester.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_tester foo) #not possible. foo is a module
add_test(NAME foo_tester COMMAND foo_tester)
```

My idea was to clone the library with a different type. But this seems very error-prone

```
function(cloneLibrary TARGET)
    get_target_property(desired_sources ${TARGET} SOURCES)
    get_target_property(desired_source_dir ${TARGET} SOURCE_DIR)
    get_target_property(desired_include_dir ${TARGET} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    get_target_property(desired_link_libraries ${TARGET} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    get_target_property(desired_name ${TARGET} NAME)

    set(obj_name ${desired_name}_objLib)
    
    add_library(${obj_name} OBJECT ${desired_sources})
    target_link_libraries(${obj_name} PUBLIC ${desired_link_libraries})
    target_include_directories(${obj_name} PUBLIC ${desired_source_dir} ${desired_source_dir}})
endfunction(cloneLibrary)
```

Is there an easier mode? Any cmake-module?

Comment: What about just `add_library(foo_link SHARED IMPORTED)` and re-import the library file? It would be better to do `add_library(foo_objects foo.cpp)` and then later `add_library(foo MODULE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_objects>)` and just link with foo_objects in tests, then to clone the library post factum.

Comment: You mean first creating the object library and the module library afterwards?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. That way you can use that object library in unit testing.